# Excel VBA Automation Error when scraping web data from site

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have created an application that scrapes data from a website.

The code runs as expected for a small number of iterations.

However, when the code is executed multiple times it crashes with an `Automation Error`.

My goal is to get daily auction results from [this website](http://seecao.com/daily-results), for multiple "border directions" and multiple "dates".

Having inspected the HTTP requests that are being sent when browsing the site I have been able to automate them and get the data I'm interested in, as follows:

```
Sub seecao()
Dim request As New WinHttpRequest
Dim htmlDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim tableTest As HTMLTable
Dim rowHTML As HTMLTableRow
Dim cellHTML As HTMLTableCell
Dim requestURL As String
Dim responseJSON As Object
Dim reqBody As String
Dim reqResponse As String
Dim seecaoBordersArray As Variant
Dim areaOut As String
Dim areaIn As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim tempRng As Range
seecaoBordersArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Help").Range("seecaoBordersRng")
requestURL = "http://seecao.com/views/ajax"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For k = LBound(seecaoBordersArray, 1) To UBound(seecaoBordersArray, 1) Step 1
    areaOut = seecaoBordersArray(k, 1)
    areaIn = seecaoBordersArray(k, 2)
    Set tempRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("seecao").Cells.Find(What:=areaOut + areaIn, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    i = tempRng.Offset(2, 0).Row
    j = tempRng.Offset(2, 0).Column
    reqBody = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Help").Range("A1:A1") + Format(Date + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd") + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Help").Range("A2:A2") + areaOut + "+-+" + areaIn + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Help").Range("A3:A3")
    With request
        .Open "POST", requestURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Host", "seecao.com"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "http://seecao.com/daily-results"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send reqBody
        reqResponse = .responseText
    End With
    Set responseJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(reqResponse)
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = responseJSON(3)("data")
    Set tableTest = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
    For Each rowHTML In tableTest.Rows
        If rowHTML.Cells(0).innerText <> "Date " Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("seecao").Cells(i, j) = rowHTML.Cells(2).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("seecao").Cells(i, j + 1) = rowHTML.Cells(5).innerText
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next rowHTML
Next k
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The body of the HTTP request consists of various parameters which form a huge string. I have split this string in 3 parts to be able to edit the "date" and "border direction" and i've stored these 3 parts in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Help").Range("A1:A1")`, `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Help").Range("A2:A2")` and `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Help").Range("A3:A3")`.

All possible "border directions" are stored in a 2x2 named range `seecaoBordersArray`. The code loops through this range, produces the corresponding request body, sends the request and gets the response.

[image: seecaoBordersArray]

The response is in JSON format. The part of the response in which I'm interested is an HTML table located in the JSON string.

The JSON string is then parsed to get the HTML table. Finally the HTML table is parsed and the data of interest are being written on a worksheet.

[image: Results printout]

As I said in the beginning of this post, the code works as expected most of the times, but it randomly crashes with an `Automation Error` depending on how many iterations are being executed.

For example it never crashes when I only execute it for 2 combinations of "borders directions".

It seems to me like some kind of performance issue rather than a bug.

Any suggestions on how to improve performance and avoid these crashes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding some `Do Events` in there?

Comment: Use & to combine strings for body btw and you could just say ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Help").Range("A1") etc

Comment: @dwirony Thank you for your reply. I am not familiar with this, but from what I've read, I understand that it will probably delay the execution even more. In what way would `Do Events` improve performance?

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for the advice. That's useful to know! Sadly it doesn't make any difference though.

Comment: need more info about the Automation error. Can you examine the crash error more? You have a request, and are re-using. Perhaps an issue. Refactor the request/HTMLDoc load into a function and make a new request each time. See what that does...